# Scaling an Android ListView without scaling the contents inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scale, android-animation

Basically I want to create a sliding menu.

I have managed to slide a ListView from left to right. Within the ListView are 3 buttons which I want to appear as the menu slides open. Unfortunately the scale animation is resizing the buttons within the ListView as it scales.

Can anyone tell me how to scale ListViews without scaling the contents of the view at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to create the ListView in negative x co-ords and then slide it fully formed into place by applying an animation to it such as this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="300" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Also, I can't tell, but from what you are saying, you are changing the size of the container  (the list) as you animate, so of course it will change the size of it's children.
A translate of some kind is probably your best option.

Comment: Thank you for your input but its not quite what I'm after. A great example of what I'm trying to achieve is the cog button on the Angry Birds opening screen. When you press the cog button the menu slides up revealing 3/4 buttons. That has the desired animation that I'm after but I require it to slide from left to right.